# Octave - Change color of different plots in the same figure

Tags: octave

I'm trying to change specific colors on several plots on the same figure in Octave. I only seem to get them to be all different or all the same, and I want two different colors.

```
X0 = [0 0];
tspan = [0:0.1:10]

global n;
n = 1;
global TFj;

figure
for TFj = 0:0.5:10
  res = lsode('redemet', X0, tspan);
  plot(tspan,res,'Linewidth',3);
  text(tspan(end),res(end,1),sprintf('TF = %f, n = %f',TFj,n))
  xlabel('Tempo Cultivo,h','Fontsize',15,'color',[0.1 0.1 0.8])
  ylabel('Especies','Fontsize',15,'color',[0.1 0.1 0.8])
  title('Expressao Genes','Fontsize',40)
  legend('mRNA','Pi')
  grid on
  hold on
end
hold off
```

redemet function represents two ODEs (dmRNA/dt and dPi/dt). I want the lines representing mRNA to be one color and the lines representing Pi to be another.

Comment: Why are you using `global` for the loop variable? Seems highly inefficient to me. You shouldn’t be using `global` at all, really.

Comment: `global` was the method our professor told us we should use when we want to evaluate how a certain parameter affects something (or in other words, when we don't want that parameter to be a fixed value). But if there's a better way of doing it, please tell me how.

Comment: You probably misunderstood your professor. Global variables are useful in very specific cases, to share variables across different functions. You have a single script, using `global` is completely superfluous and likely slows down your code here.

Comment: No I didn´t misunderstand my professor because he wrote that part of the code, I had a simplified version where n and TFj had fixed values. But I don´t really know another way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it (see [Graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNcHr.gif)).

In the line `plot(tspan,res,'Linewidth',3)` when I added the color property, I was not dividing `res` in its two results. I had to write this:

`plot(tspan,res(:,1),'Linewidth',3,'color',...,tspan,res(:,2),'Linewidth',...)`

It was the `res(:,1)` and `res(:,2)` I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the color property

```
x=2*pi*[0:.01:1];
plot(x,cos(x),"color","red")
hold on
plot(x,sin(x),"color","blue")
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I plot 1 function with 2 ODE, so for each plot that I do, two curves appear. What I want is, for each plot, the color of each ODE to be the same. For instance, if I do 3 plots in the same figure - `for TFj = 0:1:2` - I want the color of the first ODE to be green for all the plots, and the color of the second ODE to be blue for all the plots. My figure should have 3 green curves and 3 blue curves. If I do it the way you suggested, I'll have 2 curves of each color.

Comment: you can use the same method for what ever number of plots you are doing. Nothing block to plot 2 line reds, 2 blues and 2 greens

Comment: I think I'm not explaining myself well. I only want 2 colors, no matter how many plots I do and how many curves I get. Each plot generates two curves, if I have n plots, I want n curves to be blue and n curves to be red, and have no other colors. In your example you generate a single curve in each plot. My question is how do I do it when I call a function that generates two curves and I don't plot those curves separately.